# How do I access the content of the frame in different class? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, frame

I wanted to change the frame's content to the **Register.xaml** page when the **RegisterButton** is *click* but it doesn't do it. How do I properly access the frame from the MainWindow?

Please help! I've been here long enough.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
               Padding="10" BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2"/>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFrame.Content = new Navigation();

    }

    public void GoToRegister()
    {
        MainFrame.Content = new Register();
    }
}
```

**Navigation.xaml**

```
<Button x:Name="RegisterButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightSteelBlue" Content="Register" FontSize="24" Margin="10" Click="RegisterButton_Click"/>
```

**Navigation.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class Navigation : Page
{
    public Navigation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("success");
        MainWindow Main = new MainWindow();
        Main.MainFrame.Content = new Register();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Navigation` you're creating a new `MainWindow` (which you don't display) and this is why it's not working. If you want to access `MainWindow` from underlying classes (I wouldn't do it, but it's a different story), you can, for example, create a public static method that takes a `Page` as an input parameter and sets it as the content for `MainFrame`:

In your **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public static void SetMainFrameContent(Page page)
{
    this.MainFrame.Content = page;
}
```

And then in your **Navigation.xaml.cs** button click event handler you call this method:

```
private void RegisterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow.SetMainFrameContent(new Register());
    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

What also may help is setting the data context of each of the windows, simply call `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor.